# How to change backcolor of a image?

Tags: c#, image

How to change the BackColor of a transparent image to White using GDI objects without losing the content of the image.

When I tried to change it using the command 
`this.image.backcolor`, the content of the image is lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing transparent background with white color in PNG images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318549/replacing-transparent-background-with-white-color-in-png-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a bit map for image you want to change and use bitmap.clear(color u want);

Comment: Answer does not help unless you read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27318979/694852 (bitmap does not have clear method).

Answer (score 1):

First you create a new image with the desired backcolor and the same size as your original image. Then you draw the original image on the new image using Graphics.DrawImage.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you want to use `CSS trick` to do this, Here is the solution:-

`CSS`

> .reverse{-webkit-filter: invert(100%); filter: invert(100%);}

`HTML`

> <img src="src path" class="reverse">

Same way many other options are available in `CSS`.
Hope this post will help you :).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var newImage = new Bitmap(oldImage.Width, oldImage.Height);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
{
    g.Clear(Color.White);
    g.DrawImage(oldImage, new Point(0, 0));        
}
```