# C# Picturebox loaded PNG save with Picturebox Background Colour

Tags: c#, colors, background, picturebox

I need to save picturebox loaded png file with picturebox backgroud colour.

I've try with these.

But result is showing as a blank image.

help me..

```
private void bunifuThinButton24_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, pictureBox1.CreateGraphics());
        bmp1.Save(@"C:\Users\...\New folder4\ xx.jpg");
    }
```

Comment: You need to draw it. Check [Replacing transparent background with white color in PNG images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27318979/10216583)

Comment: pbox.DrawToBitmap will do just that. Or you can g.drawimage onto a fresh image cleared to someColor with g coming fromBitmap - Also: Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Comment: got it. thanks friends.

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, pictureBox1.CreateGraphics());` creates a new blank bitmap image with the resolution of pictureBox1's graphics object. you need to draw your picturebox in this bitmap. You can do this using the picturebox's DrawToBitmap function.

```
void bunifuThinButton24_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, pictureBox1.CreateGraphics());

        // fill in bitmap with the picturebox's backcolor
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1))
            {
                using (Brush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(pictureBox1.BackColor))
                {
                    g.FillRectangle(drawBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height));
                }
            }

        // draw picturebox on bitmap
        pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));

        bmp1.Save(@"C:\Users\...\New folder4\ xx.jpg");
    }
```